# Using AJAX to submit multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Out of curiosity, i am attempting to submit multiple forms with jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    // AJAX
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("form1").submit();
        $("form2").submit();

});

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form action='http://192.168.2.10/form1.php' method='post' name='form1'>
        <input type='text' name='foo' value='foo'>
    </form>

    <form action='http://192.168.2.11/form2.php' method='post' name='form2'>
        <input type='text' name='bar' value='bar'>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Problem is, i am not able to submit both as it causes an error. A friend mentioned something about a same-origin policy or i am limited to 2 requests only.

Is there some way i can submit both forms? Data returned by the forms can be ignored as they reflect values in MySQL.

Comment: What is the error you're talking about ?

Comment: I get an internal server error as the second post cancels out the first. It's not quite asynchronous.

Comment: can you copy/paste your console error ?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: To be clear. You want to do your form treatment on a different domain than your page is on ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help u.

```
$('form').each(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize());
});
```

**EDIT :**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'form1.php',
        data: $('#form1').serialize(), ///here form1 is the id of the form
        success: function(responseData) {

        }, 
        error: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: see the edit please. before called, go to your browser console and see what is the status of your request.

Comment: is form1.html the file where the form is or the destination?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: it should be "form1.php" or anything you want to put. i just give u a general method for ajax calling. if you want it for "form2" then write a method for that. if that solution isn't work, then your problem reside in server side i guess.
if server don't accept you can write down your second submission inside the first submission `success` function though its not like synchronus.

Comment: Edit :
`crossDomain: true,`

Comment: Getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource still. Only getting this issue with this script. 

$("form1").submit(); still works fine. Just not for both.

Comment: open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security

Comment: But for security issues you should not use it.

Comment: Yes, instead. I add PHP code.

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");